# C++: How to convert a Unsigned char array to a CString by value, not ASCII

Tags: c++

I would appreciate a little help fixing a bug I have with the conversion of some point data I have that is currently in a unsigned character array (Technically a vector) to a CString.

Currently my code converts the data like this:

```
std::vector <unsigned char> points;
CString strResult;
int totalpoints = 0;
// Add point data in here (x,y)
// Tick up totalpoints
strResult = CString(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&points[0]), totalpoints * 4); // I did not write this line. I'm just trying to fix it

return strResult.AllocSysString();
```

The issue arises when something attempts to read the data back out of strResult.  Some of the data changes.  I believe this is because when CString converts chars it try's to make the same character in wide format, even if the underlying value is different..  For example if I pass it the value 147 I will instead see the value 8339. I can get the value 147 from 8339 if I cast it back into a unsigned char, but where this data ultimately goes I don't have control of it. It is expected that they will get 147 with out casting, not 8339.

So The question is, how do I change the conversion to fix this?

Update: I have been examine the hex values and when the values ending up being incorrect, it's because the high byte in the CString is set to 0x20

Update 2: It might also help clarify that existing data starts as two ints. One for x and one for y.  They are separated into pairs of Bytes and stored into points.

Answer (score 1):

0x4D (dec 77) is in the ASCII range (it is the character `'M'`), so it *should* stay the same value when converted to Unicode codepoint U+004D in a wide format.

0x14B (dec 331), on the other hand, doesn't fit in an `unsigned char` to begin with.

0x93 (dec 147) fits in an `unsigned char`, but is outside of the ASCII range, so it is subject to charset interpretation, as many different charsets map 0x93 to different Unicode codepoints.

For example, Unicode codepoint U+201C (dec 8220) is indeed encoded as 0x93 in many charsets, such as all of the Windows-125x charsets, but is a different value in other charsets, typically 0xAA (dec 170) but not always.

In general, you need to know the charset that the `char` data was encoded in, to be able to convert it into a wide format without data loss. But the *values* may change, yes. That is expected behavior during a conversion between encodings.

`CString` does not allow you to specify the charset to use when converting `char` data to a wide format.  It always uses the user's default charset.  If you know the exact charset used for the `char` data, use `MultiByteToWideChar()` or equivalent to convert the data to a wide format before then assigning the result to `CString`.

---

Based on new information, you should NOT be casting your `vector` data to `char*` at all.  You are trying to store binary data into a `BSTR` (why?).  Try something more like this instead:

```
std::vector <unsigned char> points;
// fill points as needed...

CString strResult;
auto* buf = strResult.GetBufferSetLength(points.size());
std::copy(points.begin(), points.end(), buf);
strResult.ReleaseBuffer();

return strResult.AllocSysString();
```

Comment: I appreciate the insight.  But I had accidently provided some values that were not a good example of the issue.  I've updated it.

Comment: I'm not aware of any charset that maps byte 0x93 (147) to Unicode codepoint U+2093 (8339), as you claim. I suggest you provide the actual data you are looking at, both before and after the conversion.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. I'm not trying to map a character set. I'm trying to map point data (x,y). Seams silly to me, but it is part of the specification I have to work with.  Basically we take a list of x,y cords (two bytes each) stored in a unsigned character array as low byte then high for x and the same for y.  The goal is to move into a wchar (typedefed as BSTR as I found out) in the form [xl,xh,0x00,0x00,yl,yh,0x00,0x00] but xh/yh is being set to 0x20 for some values

Comment: "*I'm not trying to map a character set*" - no, YOU are not, but CSTRING is, when you construct it with a `char*` pointer when it wants `wchar_t` data instead. If your data consists of binary integers, then why are you trying to put them into a `CString` at all? In any case, if you have 2 1-byte integers `xl` and `xh` and you want to store them in a single `wchar_t`, then just cast your data to `wchar_t*` instead. If you are trying to store each integer as-is into a separate `wchar_t`, then you need to resize the `CString` to the desired length and then copy the values one at a time into it.